Why is part of commands needed for indices is defined in latex base and part is in makeidx?
It seems as if to build a minimal index
the commands \index is needed to define an entry,
\makeindex to write the idx file and \printindex to insert the index.
Whereas the first two work out of the box,
the last one is defined in package makeidx.
The command \printindex inserts the IND file at place if it exists.
It contains a theindex environment, which seems to work out of the box again.
My question is, why are all ingredients of an index defined 'in the base system' except one \printindex
when this one missing command renders the rest unusable.
Wouldnt it be more logical either to define \printindex also in the base system,
or all of the commands in a package?
Or is there a specific reason for that particular split?

as I commented on your previous question "why" questions are not really possible to answer. Leslie Lamport set it up this way in the early 1980s and it is just what it is.  It saved a few bytes and allowed some internal commands to be redefined by loading different variants eg showidx but certainly if designing this now you wouldn't do it that way.

it doesn't render it 'unusable'. you can always just \input the .ind file, after all. \printindex is just a convenience which e.g. doesn't error if the file doesn't exist etc.

This is a design pattern that is used for various things in the LaTeX ecosystem, not just makeindex but also BibTeX/biber, makeglossaries, epstopdf, Asymptote, MetaPost and many specific-purpose packages like minted, musixtex, pythontex. Sometimes this is out of necessity (you can't reimplement Python in LaTeX so you need to call pythontex between two LaTeX runs), sometimes because a good external tool already existed (minted/pygments, epstopdf, Asymptote), sometimes because the developer was more comfortable in another language (bib2gls for example), sometimes just as historical curiosity.
